# Problem with ScriptableObject. Check that the definition is in a file of the same name and that it compiles properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can´t do an ScriptableObject in unty. I do this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "SpriteDB", menuName = "AR+GPS/SpriteDB")]
public class SpriteDB : ScriptableObject
    {
        
        public class Iconos{
            
            public string nombre;
            public Sprite icon;
            public string url;
        }
        public List<Iconos> Entries;
        public Sprite GetEntryById(string Id)
        {
            Sprite result = null;

            foreach (var entry in Entries)
            {
                if (entry.nombre == Id)
                {
                    result = entry.icon;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Butwhen i create the object i get the following error:No script asset for SpriteDB. Check that the definition is in a file of the same name and that it compiles properly.
[image: files][image]

Answer (score 0):

The name of the csharp file needs to match the class name exactly. And it looks like your cs file is called `spriteDB.cs` while your class is called `SpriteDB`. Note the capital S. Rename your cs file to `SpriteDB.cs` and Unity will stop complaining.

Comment: A side note: placing script files in `Resources` is not the way to go. Put script files in a `Scripts` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Name of `MonoBehavior` or `ScriptableObject` class must match with `.cs` file name in Unity as @frankhermes said. Char case matters!

Array in not database)

```
// only Serializable types of class and struct can by display in inspector
[Serializable]
public struct IconData
{
    public string ID;
    public string URL;
    public Sprite Sprite;
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ItenDataCollection", menuName = "ItenData/Collection")]
public class ItenDataCollection : ScriptableObject
{
    // hello encapsulation, field must be privat
    // SerializeField for serialize privat field (public serialize automatically)
    [SerializeField] private IconData[] _collection;

    public Sprite GetSprite (string id)
    {
        return _collection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == id).Sprite;
    }
}
```